# Is there a way to detect that a select tag will act as a drop down or a popup window?

Tags: javascript, select, dropdown

The `<select>` tag on all desktop browser and most mobile browsers when clicked on will have a drop down of all the options. On most mobile browser instead of a drop down it will have a popup window with all the options.

Is there a way to detect if the select tag in the browser will drop down or have a popup window?

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think that's possibile, but you can detect what kind of web browser the client uses and decide based on this criteria.

Comment: What will be an accurate way to go about this. I know there are accurate ways to detect if your on mobile device or the browser width.

Comment: When I click on a select tag on my tablet it is a dropdown, when i click on a select tag on my phone it is a popup window.